# If a set is a subset of an infinte intersection, then the compliment is a superset of the infinite union

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

So as the title states I am trying to prove the following:

Show that if E ⊆ $\bigcap_{\alpha \in J}F_{\alpha}$, then $E^c \supseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}F^c _{\alpha}$

I know that I should start by arguing: if $x \in \bigcup_{\alpha \in J}F^c _{\alpha}$ then $ x \notin F^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha \in J$ However I have no idea where to go from here.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your argument is essentially half of the proof. Now that you know that $x\notin F_\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in J$,it follows from the definition of intersection that $x\notin\bigcap_{\alpha\in J}F_\alpha$. Then apply the definition of $\subseteq$ to conclude that $x\notin E$.

Answer (score 0):

$E \subseteq \bigcap_i F_i$ implies the complements reverse, so
$$
\left(\bigcap_i F_i\right)^c \subseteq E^c
$$
and now apply DeMorgan's Law.